# How to represent a 2d array by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot an array **ndarray** by matplotlib which is defined as

```
    dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(image_files), image_size, image_size),
                     dtype=np.float32)
```

My question is what is the syntax of plt.plot() will be in case of plotting arrays like this?
Thank You

Comment: it will plot each line of the `ndarray` separately. Use instead `imshow()` if you're dealing with images

Comment: thanks.. I have seen and applied all the basic tutorials but have no idea to implement imshow() in this case.. any help regarding that @MMF ?

Comment: @DavidG No, `plt.imshow(dataset)` will not work, because `imshow()` expects a 2d array `(m,l)` while has 3 dimensions, `dataset.shape = (k,m,l)`

Answer (score 1):

If your array is three dimensional you cannot directly plot it in two dimensions.

In your case it seems that you store several images along the first axis of the array. So for an array

```
dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(image_files), image_size, image_size),
                     dtype=np.float32)
```

You can plot the `i`th image out of it via

```
plt.imshow(dataset[i,:,:])
```

If this does not answer the question, you'd need to be more specific about what exactly you want to plot.

Comment: actually i want to display a sample of the labels and images from the ndarray @ImportanceOfBeingErnest